# What is the difference between importing Vue.js library and installing it via Vue-CLI?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Could you please explain what is the main difference between different Vue installation methods for building a **one-page website** (page routing) with Vue and an **Electron app** using Vue:

- importing Vue.js library via `<script>`
- installing it via Vue-CLI

This [installation guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html) doesn't really help understand the difference.

Is my site / app going to work slower if I just import Vue via `<script>`?

Comment: Using CLI to scaffhold your application gives you more flexibility.Mostly you are able to use .vue files (Single File Vue components) - thank's to Webpack and Vue Loader.

Comment: @BelminBedak is the "Single File Vue components"  the preferable method for building custom components in your sites/apps ?

Comment: In my workflow - yes.

Comment: @BelminBedak thanks, good to know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<script>` include is for including the Vue library in your webpage just like you would any other JavaScript library. `Vue` will be available on the `window` object for you to access globally. All external JavaScript must be included like this one way or another, even if you use `vue-cli`.

`vue-cli` is just a tool which generates Vue projects from templates. The setup really depends on the template that you use; I imagine most people would probably use the `webpack` template for medium to large sized Vue projects. This will initialize a node project directory containing all files necessary to develop, debug, test and build a Vue project. Webpack takes care of bundling all modules into a single JavaScript bundle which is included into the webpage via `<script>`. You can also benefit from `vue-loader` which allows you to write Vue components in `*.vue` files.

> Is my site / app going to work slower if I just import Vue via `<script>`?

I mean, not really, no (your development speed might be hindered though since you won't benefit from all the bells and whistles that `vue-cli` sets you up with). Your question applies more to the development approach that you will follow for developing a Vue web application.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So basically, from what I understood, if I just want to goof around with Vue I should just import it as a script, but if I want to build a website / app, I better use Vue-CLI because it simplifies development process and packs it nicely using Webpack. Got it thanks